# Terminology about Abelian varieties over finite fields

Tags: abelian-varieties

Is there a standard meaning for **ordinary** and **supersingular** Abelian varieties over finite fields? If so, where can I find it (together with basic properties about them)?

Answer (score 3):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse-Witt_matrix#Abelian_varieties_and_their_p-rank . "Ordinary" is always defined by p-rank equal to the dimension (the maximum possible). The article gives one definition of "supersingular", but that usage may not be universal.

Comment: The article you mentioned has a definition of supersingular but not of ordinary, right?

Comment: My answer has a definition of ordinary but not of supersingular, on the other hand.